# How to print path and key values of JSON file using JQ

Tags: json, path, jq

I would like to print each path and value of a [json](/questions/tagged/json) file with included key values line by line. I would like the output to be comma delimited or at least very easy to cut and sort using Linux command line tools. Given the following [json](/questions/tagged/json) and [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), I have been given [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) code which seems to do this for the test JSON, but I am not sure it works in all cases or is the proper approach.

Is there a function in [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) which does this automatically? If not, is there a "most concise best way" to do it?

My wish would be something like:

```
$ cat short.json | jq -doit '.'
Reservations,0,Instances,0,ImageId,ami-a
Reservations,0,Instances,0,InstanceId,i-a
Reservations,0,Instances,0,InstanceType,t2.micro
Reservations,0,Instances,0,KeyName,ubuntu
```

Test JSON:

```
$ cat short.json | jq '.'
{
  "Reservations": [
    {
      "Groups": [],
      "Instances": [
        {
          "ImageId": "ami-a",
          "InstanceId": "i-a",
          "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
          "KeyName": "ubuntu"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Code Recommended:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561460/how-to-print-path-and-key-values-of-json-file
Supporting:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/515573/convert-json-file-to-a-key-path-with-the-resulting-value-at-the-end-of-each-k
JQ Code Too long and complicated!

```
jq -r '
paths(scalars) as $p
  | [ ( [ $p[] | tostring ] | join(".") )
    , ( getpath($p) | tojson )
    ]
  | join(": ")
' short.json  

Result:  
Reservations.0.Instances.0.ImageId: "ami-a"
Reservations.0.Instances.0.InstanceId: "i-a"
Reservations.0.Instances.0.InstanceType: "t2.micro"
Reservations.0.Instances.0.KeyName: "ubuntu"
```

Answer (score 7):

A simple jq query to achieve the requested format:

```
 paths(scalars) as $p
 | $p + [getpath($p)] 
 | join(",")
```

If your jq is ancient and you cannot upgrade, insert `| map(tostring)` before the last line above.

### Output with the -r option

```
Reservations,0,Instances,0,ImageId,ami-a
Reservations,0,Instances,0,InstanceId,i-a
Reservations,0,Instances,0,InstanceType,t2.micro
Reservations,0,Instances,0,KeyName,ubuntu
```

### Caveat

If a key or atomic value contains "," then of course using a comma may be inadvisable.  For this reason, it might be preferable to use a character such as TAB that cannot appear in a JSON key or atomic value.  Consider therefore using `@tsv`:

```
paths(scalars) as $p
| $p + [getpath($p)]
| @tsv
```

(The comment above about ancient versions of jq applies here too.)

Comment: Please excuse the formatting but I am having some issues with these answers.   
$ cat short.json | jq -r 'paths(scalars) as $p | $p + [getpath($p)] | join(",")'

jq: error (at <stdin>:15): string (",") and number (0) cannot be added 

AND the first line of the tsv output does not tab delimit the value but does for subsequent lines.  

$ cat short.json | jq -r 'paths(scalars) as $p| $p + [getpath($p)]| @tsv'
Reservations    0       Instances       0       ImageId ami-a

Comment: AWS ec2 and GCE Debian instances use jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe. It looks like there is a more recent version 1.6 issued in 2018. I will try that.

Comment: Using version 1.6...the first line of the tsv output does not contain a tab delimit between  the path and the value ,, but does tab delimit the value for subsequent lines.

Comment: For the first example, both the map(tostring) option and the upgrade to version 1.6 option work as described. Thank You!

Comment: The tsv example fails to tab delimit the value for the first line. Is there an adjustment which can be made?

Comment: @mojoa - Methinks you are mistaken.

Comment: You are correct, thanks for being kind :-)   sed "s/\\t/#/g"

Answer (score 2):

Read it as a stream.

```
$ jq --stream -r 'select(.[1]|scalars!=null) | "\(.[0]|join(".")): \(.[1]|tojson)"' short.json
```

Comment: Jeff, sorry for the formatting but I am getting the following errors:                                  $ jq --stream -r 'select(.[1]|scalars) | "\(.[0]|join(".")): \(.[1]|tojson)"' short.json
jq: error (at short.json:7): string (".") and number (0) cannot be added
jq: error (at short.json:8): string (".") and number (0) cannot be added
jq: error (at short.json:9): string (".") and number (0) cannot be added
jq: error (at short.json:11): string (".") and number (0) cannot be added

Comment: Sounds like you're using an older version of jq, you'll need to convert all parts of the key to strings. `select(.[1]|scalars) | "\([.[0][]|tostring]|join(".")): \(.[1]|tojson)"`

Comment: Both examples work, Thanks! Not as compact as I had hoped for though. I really would like for this type of output to be a function of JQ as a switch.

Comment: Well it is there in streams for the most part, just not in the format you want.

Comment: @JeffMercado - If your proposed solution is to be generic, the `select` should be `select(length==2)`.

Comment: @peak: Empty objects and arrays as well as null are potential values when streamed and I doubt they would be useful to include for this case so opted to filter them all out. That would have made it `select(length==2 and (.[1]|scalars))` but was reduced to simply `select(.[1]|scalars)`.

Comment: @peak: though after further inspection, it looks like this doesn't quite work correctly as `false` is being filtered out as well. So some adjustments are needed.

Comment: @peak - I did not notice before, but all these solutions actually eliminate the line "Groups". I would like all lines represented in the output.

Comment: @moja: If that's the case, then it should just be `select(length==2)`...

Comment: @JeffMercado - It appears as though the solution does not handle nested JSON like  "topping":
  [
   { "id": "5001", "type": "None" }, - outputs - topping.0.id: "5001" Is there a way to handle any number of nested arrays? Sorry, I did not state this requirement as I am learning.  https://opensource.adobe.com/Spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html - Example 4

Comment: @mojoa: That looks correct for me. For that snippet I would expect to see `topping.0.id: "5001"` and `topping.0.type: "None"`

Comment: I do not deal with data structures much, but conceptually it seems like the output line topping.0.type: "None" looses the context of being "id: "5001". I would expect the full context of Type none mentioned. In other words, Output topping.0.type: "None" does not reveal that its ID is 5001.

Comment: It'd be perfect if array indices were enclosed in square brackets.  If each path then began with `.`, each one would be a valid jq query string.

Answer (score 0):

Use -c paths as follows:

```
cat short.json | jq -c paths | tr -d '[' | tr -d ']'
```

I am using **jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe**