# Counting the index of a partial JSON

Tags: c#

My plan is to do a JSON diff tool.

I am using a diff tool and I would like to show the result in the UI. The diff tool returns the path, where the two JSON has differences.

I would like to select that part on the UI in a RichTextBox. It's easy to do that if I have the start index and the length of the selection.

I have the JSON as a `JObject`. I have a path so I can use `SelectToken(path)` on it. It returns the token correctly.

Let's see the example:

original

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "c": "d",
      "f": "g"
    }
  ]
}
```

path: `a[0]`

The return of the `SelectToken(path).Parent` will be:

```
{
  "c": "d",
  "f": "g"
}
```

So I loose the "indentation". I would like to use `string.IndexOf` or similar because I need the index where that part starts. But because of the whitespaces the IndexOf is not working.

Do you have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to do? Why do you need the index of the position in a JSON string?

Comment: My plan is to do a JSON diff tool. I have the difference and the path and I would like to select that part on the UI in a RichTextBox. It's easy to do that if I have the start index and the length of the selection

Comment: If you're doing a diff tool, compare the object itself, not the string representation of the JSON object.

Comment: But I am using a diff tool, but I would like to show the result in the UI. The diff tool returns the path, where the two JSON has difference

Comment: @rhobaj Please [edit] your question to include these additional information to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the [`JToken.Parse()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parse_1.htm) method to parse a JSON string, you can provide a [`JsonLoadSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JsonLoadSettings.htm) object for the configuration of the `Parse()` method. It has a [`LineInfoHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JsonLoadSettings_LineInfoHandling.htm) property, which allows you to specify if "line information" should be loaded while parsing. When you set this setting to [`Load`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_LineInfoHandling.htm), you will get relevant line number and position from the original JSON string as part of the [`IJsonLineInfo`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_ijsonlineinfo.htm) interface. See the following example:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }   
    public string Comment { get; set; } 
    public InnerObject Foobar {get; set;}
}

public class InnerObject {
    public int X {get; set;}
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\n"+
                      "    \"Name\": \"foobar\",\n"+
                      "    \"Foobar\":\n"+
                      "         {\n"+
                      "             \"X\": 42\n"+
                      "         }\n"+
                      "}";
        
        Console.WriteLine("Original JSON string:");
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        JToken token = JToken.Parse(json, new JsonLoadSettings() {
            LineInfoHandling = LineInfoHandling.Load
        });
        JToken searchToken = token.SelectToken("Foobar");
        Console.WriteLine("Found JSON token:");
        Console.WriteLine(searchToken);
        IJsonLineInfo jsonLineInfo = (IJsonLineInfo)searchToken;
        Console.WriteLine($"Original JSON token found in line {jsonLineInfo.LineNumber} at position {jsonLineInfo.LinePosition}");
    }
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
Original JSON string:
{
    "Name": "foobar",
    "Foobar":
         {
             "X": 42
         }
}
Found JSON token:
{
  "X": 42
}
Original JSON token found in line 4 at position 10
```

Based on these information you can calculate the original string index of the input JSON string by counting the length of each previous line and add the "remaining" position of the current line, returned by the `IJsonLineInfo` interface.

Comment: That's it, thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

This question seems to do what you are looking for, it might be of help
([How to print path and key values of JSON file using JQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59700329/how-to-print-path-and-key-values-of-json-file-using-jq))

```
$ $ cat test.json
{
  "a": [
    {
      "c": "d",
      "f": "g"
    },
    {
      "h": "j",
      "k": "m"
    }
  ]
}
$ jq -r '
paths(scalars) as $p
  | [ ( [ $p[] | tostring ] | join(".") )
    , ( getpath($p) | tojson )
    ]
  | join(": ")
'  test.json
a.0.c: "d"
a.0.f: "g"
a.1.h: "j"
a.1.k: "m"
$
```

**jq** is available on the [download jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/download/) page.

A C# answer might be available here, TL/DR: [Read and parse a Json File in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297563/read-and-parse-a-json-file-in-c-sharp), which can be adapted to your own needs.

A C# solution:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText(@"D:/temp/test.json");

        var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);

        doit(data);

        void doit(JToken d)
        {
            foreach (JToken item in d.Values())
            {
                if (item.HasValues) Console.WriteLine($"{item.Path}");
                doit((JToken)item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
a
a[0].c
a[0].f
a[1].h
a[1].k
```

Comment: I would like to do it with C#

Comment: added a C# solution.